# Is it common to show UML class diagrams for each module in a system?

Tags: uml

For a project of mine, I have to show a UML class diagram. However, the system is largely GUI based, which is making the class diagram huge and messy. Is it common to break up the diagram for a system such as this into several diagrams, one for each module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not only common, it is recommended.

And if you fear to lose the global vision, you can do a global cross-module diagram, but with only the most important classes (which will be the "hearts" of the various modules), and then all the module-scoped diagrams.

Comment: This is what I am doing, and it certainly looks much cleaner. I would upvote your answer, if I could.